# how to get an collection of ids int[] in post action (selected checkboxes)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to get in an action method the values from the selected checkboxes on a form 
how would you do that ? (or probably get them all and see who was selected)

```
public ActionResult (int[] ids)
```

...

```
<input type="checkbox" value = "1" />
<input type="checkbox" value = "2" />
<input type="checkbox" value = "3" />
<input type="checkbox" value = "4" />

<%=Html.Submit(); %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try giving the checkboxes a name (ids):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="4" />
```

Should work with:

```
public ActionResult Index(int[] ids) { ... }
```